# ckeditor not working in rails_admin: Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.customHandlers[e.type] is not a constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ckeditor

I am having problems getting **ckeditor** to work in **rails_admin** in production. It is working in local development mode. ckeditor is working on my app, but it is not working in rails_admin. I am getting this error in the Google Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.customHandlers[e.type] is not a constructor
```

I am using:

- Rails 4.2.2
- Ruby 2.2.4
- Heroku
- gem galetahub/ckeditor (4.2.2)
- gem sferik/rails_admin (0.8.1)
- ckeditor's external plugin [mediaembed](http://ckeditor.com/addon/embed)

This is the code I am using to get the ckeditor to show up in rails_admin:

```
field :description, :ck_editor
```

I have tried **fetching the gems from github**, but the same problem persists.

Any idea what I am not doing right, given that ckeditor *does* work in my heroku app?

Let me know if I am missing information that might be helpful to debug this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line to **app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js**:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

and it works now! I previously only added to **application.js**